# PHP url variable gives blank result

Tags: php, get, urlvariables

I am trying to pass a variable to PHP page using URL GET but I get blank space, what is wrong?!

```
url: http://localhost:2651/index_main.php?teamName=Liverpool
```

here is the destination PHP file:

```
<?php
  $teamName = $_GET['teamName'];
?>
<html>
<body>
<?php
$searchQuery = $api->searchTeam(urlencode('<?php $_GET["teamName"]; ?>')) // here must get the team name from previous page
?>
<h3>All home matches of <?php echo $team->_payload->name; ?>:</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If by blank space you mean the [white screen of death](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death), please, [check for errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: A blank page usually means you have a problem but error_reporting is turned off. [See here for how to turn reporting on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: `$searchQuery = $api->searchTeam(urlencode('<?php $_GET["teamName"]; ?>'))` you did close that off, right? If not, then it's a parse error and risks on being closed because of it.

Comment: What "blank space"?  What is the *actual output*?  Note that you're not outputting the URL value at all, but instead the result of some other operation we know nothing about.  Instead of assuming that PHP's use of a query string is broken, *maybe* look into the possibility that this other complex operation in your code *might* be the problem?

Comment: Where is `$team` defined?

Comment: @FirstOne The OP seems to have since ran back into their rabbit hole; gave up on it. Coffee's getting ready too, so I can't miss the ultimate water's boiling point.

Comment: Solved by ac.freelancer

Comment: @Isabella That person added a missing semi-colon (and stuff).  You sure that all that was missing in your code? You never bothered answering to any comments left under your question. I love it when someone just keeps us all hanging.

Comment: I 'v added it, thank you all :)

Comment: lol.. I'm outta here.,. @Fred-ii- I suggest you to let go and do the same.. (This comment will be gone soon)

Comment: @FirstOne I've a good mind to close it as a parse error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them which is most likely the case here, given the comment about *"I've added it"* about my comment for the missing semi-colon which I feel is all that was wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your code is not clean, you use too many php tags. Here is your code now :

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $teamName = $_GET['teamName'];
    $searchQuery = $api->searchTeam(urlencode($teamName)); // here must get the team name from previous page
    ?>
    <h3>All home matches of <?php echo $team->_payload->name; ?>:</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Second, in your `urlencode`, you put additional php tags and you didn't use the variable you just set before.

Comment: Hm.. my daily voting limit's already been reached..

Comment: @FirstOne Being what; *up* or *down*? hehe

Comment: ac.freelancer This worked, tx.